# Doing to joins on a table that already has an alias

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an association on a self referencing table which requires an alias.

I'm currently trying to query the table twice. However I'm running into a
`Transaction (OneTimeDebits) is not associated to Transaction!` error.

It seems that since the self referencing association requires an alias there is no way to query the association with a different alias.

Is there some way I can get around this?

```
models.Transaction.hasMany(models.Transaction, { as: 'Debits', foreignKey: 'PaymentId' });
models.Transaction.belongsTo(models.Transaction, { as: 'Payment', foreignKey: 'PaymentId' });

models.Transaction.findAll({
  where: {
    '$OneTimeDebits.id$': null,
  },
  include: [{
          model: models.Transaction,
          where: {
            OneTime: true,
          },
          required: false,
          as: 'OneTimeDebits',
        },
        {
          model: models.Transaction,
          where: {
            FinalDebit: true,
          },
          as: 'FinalDebits',
  }],
});
```

Comment: Please also post the error.